# How to access the DEVICES list as in the Finder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I try to show a list of computer devices in my application like in the Finder. How can I access this list and also get notified if a device is attached or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question (how to access the list of available devices), see [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515068/list-all-drives-partitions-and-get-dev-rdisc-device-with-cocoa).

To get notifications of device availability and removal, see [NSWorkspace's notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIEFIDI).